# Get sum of sub arrays in a key value array together

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mulit demensional array like this ...

[image]

** note the array has closing brackets which is  not shown in this image. so theres no issue in the syntax.

I want to add the values in each key (Openness, Conscientiousness) together so that i have a array like :

```
      Array{
              [Openness]=> Array(
                    [0] => 16
             )
              [Conscientiousness]=>Array (
                     [0]=> 10
              )
         }
```

When i tried this code after looking through existing questions :

```
      $sumArray = array();

    foreach ($finalarr as $k=>$subArray) {
      foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        //$sumArray[$id]+=$value;
        array_key_exists( $id, $sumArray ) ? $sumArray[$id] += $value :      $sumArray[$id] = $value;
            }
        }

   print_r($sumArray);
```

I get :

[image]

which is not what i want. ANy ideas how to fix the array?

Comment: Take a look at `array_sum()`

Comment: The keys of `$sumArray` should be `$k`, not `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `array_sum()` and one loop:

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($finalarr as $k => $subArray) {
    $sumArray[$k] = array_sum($subArray);
}
```

If you really need the elements of `$sumArray` to be arrays rather than just the sums, it becomes:

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($finalarr as $k => $subArray) {
    $sumArray[$k] = array(array_sum($subArray));
}
```

But I'm not sure why you would want that.

Comment: I get a error saying array_sum expects parameter 1 to be array when i run the first bit of your coding. anyways i have posted my solution taking into accout all the comments.

Comment: I don't see how yours can work when mine doesn't. You're calling `array_sum()` with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as suggested in the comments i used the array_sum and it worked. I changed the foreach to :

**removed the inner loop which was unnecessary

```
    foreach ($finalarr as $k=>$subArray) {

        $finalarr[$k]=array_sum($subArray);

}
```

and it gave me the output :

```
     Array{
          [Openness]=> 16
          [Conscientiousness]=> 10

     }
```

Thanks for the comments !!

Comment: What's the point of the inner loop? You never use `$id` or `$value`. You're just doing the same sum of `$subArray` repeatedly.

Comment: Where are those parentheses in the output coming from? You have `)` with no matching `(`.

Comment: I removed the inner loop and got the same result so your right that second loop is not needed ! thanks.

Comment: So what's the difference from my answer?

Comment: i dont know. when i run your code i get the error i mentioned

Comment: But my code is identical to yours now! Do I have a typo somewhere?

Comment: The only difference is that you're putting the result back into the original `$finalarr`, while I'm putting it into `$sumArray`. But that shouldn't affect what `array_sum($subArray)` does.